# TypeScript type inference issue with string literal with JSX

Tags: typescript, jsx, type-inference

Let's say I have this component:

```js
interface Colors {
  white: string
  black: string
}

const theme: Colors = {
  white: "#fff",
  black: "#000",
}

const TextWrapper = styled.p<{ color: keyof Colors }>`
  color: ${({ color }) => theme[color]};
`
```

and I want to use it like that:

```js
<TextWrapper color={'white'} >Hello world!</TextWrapper>
```

but I get this error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"white" | "black"'.`
I've tried to force the inference by using `as const`, `as 'white'` or `as keyof Colors`

But the only thing that worked is to declare a const and use it as the prop

```js
const color = 'white'

<TextWrapper color={color} >Hello world!</TextWrapper>
```

Otherwise, the string is not inferred.

Is there a way to disable this check in my `tsconfig` or a more simple workaround?

Comment: Not sure this will help, but have you tried: `<TextWrapper color='white' >...`?

Comment: try <TextWrapper :color="color" >Hello world!</TextWrapper>

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wX2v1m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.